# Command-line options for HH and opening CHM Windows Help Files

Tags: windows, chm, html-help

I'd like to be able to write [Inquisit](http://www.millisecond.com/) scripts in Vim.
In the standard Inquisit application for writing scripts, I can press F1 and it brings up help on the topic related to the word under the cursor.
I'd like to set up the same functionality through Vim.

The help file for Inquisit is stored in a Windows .CHM file.

I figured there must be a set of command-line options for doing a keyword search in a chm file, but I haven't been able to find a complete list of the command-line options, presumably  for HH.exe.

- I did find [HTML Help command-line article from help-info.de](http://www.help-info.de/en/Help_Info_HTMLHelp/hh_command.htm) with a few pointers, but it does not have a full listing of command-line options.
- I also found [this discussion on AutoHotKey discussion board](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic10285.html). It mentions [keyhh](http://www.keyworks.net/keyhh.htm).
- I also just found [a vimscript designed to do exactly what I want](https://github.com/vim-scripts/winhelp)

Questions:

- Is there a complete list of command-line options for HH.exe?
- Is there a better way of going about what I am trying to do?

Comment: Link the chmlib package against VIM and use that?

Answer (score 3):

If you can script in AutoHotkey ,I just found a solution. The idea will be to use VIM to pass reqd. command line-parameters to a compiled Ahk script which will in turn open the help file a/c the data.

In this solution, it will be also assumed that all the keywords that you are to search lie in the Index list (as they do).

To open the Helpfile, then Index tab & search, the following AHK Code works --

```
Run, %Helpfile%  ; your help file
Winwaitactive, ahk_class HH Parent
SendMessage, 0x1330, 1,, SysTabControl321
sleep, 0 
SendMessage, 0x130C, 1,, SysTabControl321
Send,+{Home}%1%{Enter}
```

where `%1%` is the only command line param passed to the compiled Ahk script.

So, VIM can passe Commandline params as `start compiledahk.exe "<Keyword>"`.

Comment: Or you can visit my Ahk work [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/94493-context-sensitive-help-in-any-editor-best-edition/) on a script that runs context sensitive f1 help **in any editor**.