# Way to open Index tab in chm file

Tags: chm

How to open **Index** tab in chm Help viewer at runtime. I looked at the following topic -- 
[Force CHM help window move to Index or Search tab initially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504013/force-chm-help-window-move-to-index-or-search-tab-initially)
but it didn't help me as it was about adding the feature to the chm file as if you were its author , not opening any other chm file with the **Index** tab active.

So, the summary is that I want to open a help file such that the Index tab is active.

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: AutoHotkey, but I think I have somehow solved it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976872/command-line-options-for-hh-and-opening-chm-windows-help-files/17182809#17182809) . This method uses a Macro,but do you know any command-line method to fill data in the Index tab automatically.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to open any CHM help file with index tab opened on a PC with Windows installed. To say it right now - as far as I know - this isn't possible without a wrapper application and going deep into HTMLHelp API.

Try following steps:
1. Open a CHM help file having all the tabs "Content", "Index" and "Search" on your your Windows machine.
2. Choose the "Index" tab.
3. Close the Help Viewer window "x"
4. Open this CHM help file again and the "Index" tab is active.
Next try:
1. Open another CHM help file and normally the "Content" is active.
2. Choose the "Index" tab.
3. Close the Help Viewer window "x"
4. Open this second CHM help file again and the "Index" tab is active.

Please note this is depending on hh.dat - a Windows system file. So, it's depending on the users action (clicks) too.

Which purpose does the file hh.dat serve?

The hh.dat file stores user-specific information on all the HTMLHelp files (*.CHM) on your system (position, favourite topics, search history, etc.), and can cause a error if it has somehow been corrupted.
Delete or rename the file hh.dat to reset all (!) CHM windows on your system to their default settings.
You should find hh.dat in this directory: \Documents and Settings\%username%\Application Data\Microsoft\HTML Help
or C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\HTML Help
Windows will create a new version of hh.dat when you next open any .chm file.

A ClickOnce example application from my site is using following code to call help with index tab:

```
  Private Sub btnShowHelpIndex_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnShowHelpIndex.Click
Dim sPath As String = Replace(Application.StartupPath.ToString, "\bin", "")
'--- Show index of the help file (tricky fix!).
Help.ShowHelp(Me, sPath & "/hlp/CHM-example.chm", HelpNavigator.Index, "windmill")
'--- Open help window and show topic for this keyword.
'--- If this fails a nearby index item is shown (not tested). 
Help.ShowHelp(Me, sPath & "/hlp/CHM-example.chm", HelpNavigator.KeywordIndex, "windmill")
```

[image]