# How to start help via hh.exe at specific index

Tags: windows, chm

I'm opening windows' help file via

`hh.exe "C:\MyHelp.chm"`

and everything works fine, but I'd additionally want to start at some Index e.g `Test abc`

is it somehow possible to do it? e.g some command-line parameters? I only managed to find those:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/htmlhelp/using-command-line-switches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is NO for a command-line call.

You know - **hh.exe** is distributed with HTML Help so you can rely on it being present. It lives in the Windows folder and has a limited number of command-line options. HH.EXE is associated with .CHM files. So double-click a *.CHM file and Windows will open the file using HH.EXE. Its a very small file, it mostly passes the help filename onto a HH API library. HH.EXE is not single instance, if you open a CHM file three times using HH.EXE, then three help windows will appear.

Please note the options you have. See below and also: [HTMLHelp command-line](https://www.help-info.de/en/Help_Info_HTMLHelp/hh_command.htm).

**Example of opening a help topic using help ID = 12030**

ID is a number that you've defined in the [MAP] section of your project (*.hhp) file and mapped to the required topic in the [ALIAS] section.

```
C:\>HH.EXE -mapid 12030 ms-its:C:/xTemp/XMLconvert.chm
```

**Example of opening a help topic using a topic path**

```
C:\>HH.EXE ms-its:C:/xTemp/XMLconvert.chm::/Bekannte_Fehler/err/xml3.htm
C:\>HH.EXE mk:@MSITStore:C:/xTemp/XMLconvert.chm::/Bekannte_Fehler/errxml3.htm

C:\>HH.EXE ms-its:C:/xTemp/XMLconvert.chm::/Bekannte_Fehler/err/xml3.htm#anchor
```

The mk:@MSITStore protocol works with IE3 and above while ms-its works with IE4 and above. A shorter version of "ms-its" is to just use "its". Actually, the later versions of HH don't even require the protocol prefix.

**By Software** this can be done by e.g. vb.net:

[Way to open Index tab in chm file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17182342/1981088)